# Displaying web page with PyQt5 WebEngine

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I encountered some problems with the use of the library QtWebEngineWidgets.
The main idea is to display PDF in a QWebEngineView, so I want firstly to display simply a web page like https://google.com.

I tested a lot of code from different websites and forums but I have always the same problem, the PyQt page show nothing.

I would like to get your attention to a code from codeloop (https://codeloop.org/python-how-to-make-browser-in-pyqt5-with-pyqtwebengine/)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()

web.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))

web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

( I chose this because it's a simple code and illustrate perfectly the problem that I encounter all the time )

[image: Code and page]

I remain open to all your answers and comments.

{EDIT}
I have :
PyQt5          5.15.0
PyQt5-sip      12.8.0
PyQtWebEngine  5.15.0

[image]

(Dialog box: The application failed to start correctly)

Comment: What version of pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine do you have installed? you could run your script from CMD/console

Comment: did u consider the dialogue boxes? the code works fine. may be some problem with the istallation

Comment: Thank for your answer @eyllanesc, I edited my post with the versions. I found an error when I launch the program: I put a screenshot in my post.
edit: you talk about a dialog box like in my screenshot ?

Comment: @FabienDenoyelle I don't understand the error message, can you translate to english?  Also try install pyqt5 pyqtwebengine older: `python -m pip install pyqt5==5.14.0 pyqtwebengine==5.14.0`

Comment: It had no influence, I still have the same error message.

Comment: `[14216:4056:0726/183251.559:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: AccÞs refusÚ. (0x5) (((--> access denied )))
[14216:4056:0726/183251.560:ERROR:cache_util.cc(141)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\denoy\AppData\Local\python3\QtWebEngine\Default\GPUCache to C:\Users\denoy\AppData\Local\python3\QtWebEngine\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[14216:4056:0726/183251.560:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(178)] Unable to create cache`

It is in my console when I launch the code.

Comment: @FabienDenoyelle the problem for what are the permissions, try creating a virtualenv and there install pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine. Please use `@username`

Comment: Ok thank @eyllanesc, I tried with Administrator mod of the cmd without success. I never work on virtual environments. I will therefore document myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @eyllanesc, in fact the problem is with permissions. By creating a virtual environment according to the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), my program work perfectly.